# JQuery - I don't succeed to set value in modal form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a form that let visitors put in a check in date and fix value of the hotel name.

This is the html code, it has a form and a modal form generated by Contact Form 7 ( this latest with the `<form> ... </form>` tags :

```
<form name="request_to_book" id="request_to_book" class="form form-small">
 <div class="form-group">
…
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-check-in relative s6">
                        <input type="text" name="check_in" value="01 4, 2023" readonly="" class="form-control check_in " placeholder="m j, Y">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar field-icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
…
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <input type="hidden" id="hotel_title" name="hotel_title" value="Hilton Osaka Hotel" readonly="">
            </div>
      </div>
                <div class="pl25 pr25 pb20">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-success btn-full btn-medium bold" href="#modal-contact-form">
                    Request to book                </a>
       </div>
        <div id="modal-contact-form" class="modal" data-created_overlay="true">
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <h4 class="bold">Request to book</h4>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-flat"><h3>Close</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f1420-p62-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
…
<p><label> Your Name (required)<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Email (required)<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Villa : <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="hotel_title"><input type="text" name="hotel_title" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" readonly="readonly" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </label><br>
…
<p><label> Check-in date (required)<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="check_in"><input type="text" name="check_in" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </label></p>
...
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit"></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true"></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close-form-book"><i class="flaticon-error"></i></a>
```

I just want to copy the data of the form into the modal form :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#request_to_book').change(function() {
        selected_value = jQuery("input[name='hotel_title']").val();
//        alert(selected_value);
        jQuery("#modal-contact-form input[name='hotel_title']").val( selected_value );

        selected_value = jQuery("input[name='check_in’]”).val();
//        alert(selected_value);
        jQuery(".modal-contact-form input[name='check_in']").val( selected_value );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Getting the value works perfectly, the alert confirms it.
But I am not able to set the value of "check_in" within the modal contact form.

To clarify :

1. selected_value = jQuery("input[name='hotel_title']").val();
   gives the hotel name, with this html code it gives "Hilton Osaka Hotel"
2. jQuery("#modal-contact-form input[name='hotel_title']").val( selected_value );
   seems to do nothing, but it should set the input-tag with name="hotel_title" to "Hilton Osaka Hotel", so it seems it doesn't find the input-tag. This is my problem.

Can anybody help me please ? I do something wrong.

Comment: are those curly quotes a copy paste error? they just so happen to be in the code relevant to the check_in input.

Comment: I think it is just a copy/paste error, but the double quotes are needed in the JQuery

Comment: "not able to", how? Is there an error?

Comment: at this point nothing appears wrong enough to make it not work, other than the curly quotes, assuming you are correct that the other parts are working fine.

Comment: In fact what I mean is that the value is not set in the "check_in"-value of the modal form. So in fact it does do nothing.
=> jQuery("#modal-contact-form input[name='hotel_title']").val( selected_value );

Comment: @Tasari eh, no, that's not a fact. If selected_value is an empty string, then it setting it to an empty string would in fact be doing something. The logic you are using here is prone to failing because your selector to get a value to set to the input also covers the input you are setting a value to.

Comment: Like I wrote, it gets the value correctly for each field, I want to copy it ( the alert proofs it ). Of course I knew if empty value, it won't set the other field, which is logical. But the value for all 10 fields ( I removed all other fields, if not it is too long ) are correctly given and set to "selected_value"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to change the text in inside the span with the name="check-in".

With jQuery you cannot change the `.val()` of a span you have to use `.text()`.

Instead of this.

```
 jQuery(".modal-contact-form input[name='check_in']").val( selected_value );
```

Do this `.text()` (If HTML tags exist in this text they are stripped)

```
 jQuery(".modal-contact-form input[name='check_in']").text( selected_value );
```

Using  `.html( selected_value )` in jQuery will work as well. If `selected_ value` has HTML tags in it those tags will be added inside the span.

Also check your quotes: make sure you are using the correct quotes selected_value = jQuery("input[name='check_in’]`”`).val();